# RSpec match_array in Ruby Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSpec, `match_array` matcher lets you examine if two arrays have equal elements without concerning orders. I would like to know the equivalent matcher in Ruby Test::Unit module.

i.e. How would you write the following without using RSpec?

**RSpec**

```
expect([1,2,3,4]).to match_array [4,3,2,1] 
# => true
```

Comment: You write your own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific function in Ruby Unit Test library that support the match any operation. Thought this is a pretty trivial using the subtract operator on two arrays then checking if they are empty.

Let a and b be an array of integers arranged in different order

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,3,2,1]
(a - b)
# => empty array
(a - b).empty?
# => true
```

So putting that together would be

```
def match_array(array1, array2)
  (array1 - array2).empty?
end

match_array(a, b)
# => true
```

Further you could use the [Test::Unit#assert_block](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_block)

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestArray < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_array
    assert_block do
      ([1,2,3,4] - [4,3,2,1]).empty?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't work if they arrays are of different size but contain duplicated elements: `[1,2,3,4,4] - [4,3,2,1]` is empty but they should not match.